# MySQL external access for localhost

Tags: mysql, apache

I need to connect a desktop application to a MySQL server. The website connect to the database 'localhost'. What would the the full path of the localhost be?

Using CentOS 6.5/apache/zpanel

The answer is probably so obvious that nobody has ever asked it before. But I rally can't figure it out. Here is the screenshot of what I have:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, you have a desktop app and a webapp? both to same MySQL server?. Please explain

Comment: Try the hostname of the server, or its IP address. 99% chance that it'll be firewalled though - and in the case of the other 1% it damn well should've been.

Comment: usually if you connect to remote host, you use ip adress of the host as server variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the IP address of the server which is running mysql (the same of the webserver, if you're connecting to it as localhost)

But many hosting companies disable remote MySQL by default, you may need to ask them to enabled it, or to whitelist the IP you are connecting from.

Answer (score 1):

You have to grant access to the user you are using to connect from remote, on your case the `root` user so:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'
  IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

After this run this other command to refresh the new privileges

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The '%' is the option that you allow root to connect from anywhere. You can specify also an IP address.